# Install Onsen UI 2 without Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

How to install Onsen UI 2 without Angular? Here http://onsen.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/docs/guide/js/ are different guides but when I do the javscript one (> npm install onsenui) I always get ReferenceError: angular is not defined how to install it right without Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `npm install onsenui@2.0.0`, although that should be the default version.

Onsen UI does not require AngularJS or any other framework, it can be used with pure JavaScript if you want.